# How to fetch a list from document using n1ql with spring-data-couchbase

Tags: spring-boot, nosql, couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I want to fetch actions list in user class by username with this query but its not working

```
@Repository
public interface IUserRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<User,Long> {

@Query("SELECT actions from #{#n1ql.bucket} where #{#n1ql.filter} and userName = $1 ")
List<Action> getActionsByUserName(String userName);
```

where am ı doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide more detail about what's not working? Is there an error? What's not happening that you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

__id and __cas must be projected.  They are included in n1ql.selectEntity

@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where #{#n1ql.filter} and userName = $1 ")

Or you can project them yourself :

@Query("SELECT actions, meta().id as __id, meta().cas as __cas  from #{#n1ql.bucket} where#{#n1ql.selectEntity} where  where #{#n1ql.filter} and userName = $1 ")